# How Do I Order This Query?

Tags: php, mysql

I want to order this query descending by ID.

I get the error `mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1`

```
$checkquery = "SELECT COUNT(message), user, date_time FROM messages";           
$collctmsg = mysql_query($checkquery, $db_connect);
$no_rows = mysql_fetch_row($collctmsg);
$numrows = $no_rows[0];
$rows_per_page = 5;
$lastpage = ceil($numrows/$rows_per_page);
$pageno = (int)$pageno;
if ($pageno > $lastpage) {
   $pageno < $lastpage;
} // if
if ($pageno < 1) {
   $pageno = 1;
} // if
$limit = 'LIMIT ' .($pageno - 1) * $rows_per_page .',' .$rows_per_page;

$messageshow = "SELECT message, user, date_time FROM messages {$limit}, ORDER BY id DESC";
$message_execution = mysql_query($messageshow, $db_connect);
```

Comment: Show us the actual PHP code, not simply the query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Limit last, and no comma between your limit clause and you order by clause

```
SELECT message, user, date_time FROM messages ORDER BY id DESC {$limit}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is done using the ORDER BY clause:

```
SELECT message, user, date_time FROM messages ORDER BY id DESC
```

Comment: Dude Here's My Query But it is not ordering....

SELECT message, user, date_time FROM messages {$limit} ORDER BY id DESC

Comment: @PHPSrike Your LIMIT needs to be after the ORDER BY http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/select.html

Comment: Ok I solved it, this is the real query

    SELECT message, user, date_time FROM messages ORDER BY id DESC {$limit}

Thank you everyone
Its just i've to place order by before specifying limit.

Answer (score 1):

Update your query. After limit No need to put coma:

```
$messageshow = "SELECT message, user, date_time FROM messages {$limit} ORDER BY id DESC";
```